# filter dataframe based on array in python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has an array as one of its values

```
   Alg    iMap_x
0  Max()  [12,34]
1  Min()  [43,11,84,33]
2  Sum()  [93,15,3,99,37]
```

I want to filter my dataframe based on `iMap_x` value

I have `i = [43,11,84,33]`

when i try this code it does not work

```
df[df["iMap_x"] == i]["Alg"]
```

this gives error

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (4,), (2,))
```

I also tried

```
df[df["iMap_x"].isin(i)]["Alg"]
```

but gave no values (empty dataframe)

I tried

```
df["iMap_x"].isin(i)
```

but gave all false

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
```

any idea how to do that?

Comment: One possibility from the dupe: `df[df.iMap_x.map(tuple).isin([tuple(i)])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df2 = df['iMap_x'].apply(lambda x: x == i)
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Alg':['Max()','Min()','Sum()'], 'iMap_x':[[12,34],[43,11,84,33],[93,15,3,99,37]]})
print('df:',df,sep='\n')

i = [43,11,84,33]
df2 = df['iMap_x'].apply(lambda x: x == i)
print('df2:',df2,sep='\n')
```

Input:

```
df:
     Alg               iMap_x
0  Max()             [12, 34]
1  Min()     [43, 11, 84, 33]
2  Sum()  [93, 15, 3, 99, 37]
```

Output:

```
df2:
0    False
1     True
2    False
```

If you want to use this criteria to filter rows then select the `Alg` column, you can do this:

```py
df3 = df[df['iMap_x'].apply(lambda x: x == i)]['Alg']
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
1    Min()
Name: Alg, dtype: object
```

Comment: @asmgx Do you need additional help with your question?